# make Google Chrome switches specific to a window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Put in the same batch file (.bat), the following will open two chrome windows with the same size and position:

start chrome --window-position=100,100 --window-size=100,100 --new-window "http://example.com"
start chrome --window-position=200,200 --window-size=200,200 --new-window "http://example.com"

Why? How can I make each window obey the switches independently?